# How to fix Kendo-CSP issue after upgrading Telerik R1 2023 version without using 'Unsafe' prefix?

Tags: jquery-ui, telerik-mvc, content-security-policy

we are working to fix the issue with Kendo-CSP for ASP.Net MVC with jQuery Kendo UI. In our application currently, we are using Kendo grids, dropdowns, and popups.
Initially, we implemented the below changes for CSP.

- Update to jQuery 3.6.4
- Generated the Dynamic nonce numbers and applied nonce for inline scripts
- Ajax calls replaces with Jquery get/post methods.
- Removed all styles and replaced them with bootstrap classes.
- Onclik and Onchanges events replace with javascript addevent-listeners.
- Added the Unsafe prefix in the configuration (waiting for the Kendo 2023 R1 version)

Recently we got a new version of Telerik R1 2023, Replaced the below files for Upgrade.

- Kendo.mvc.dll
- kendo.aspnetmvc.js
- kendo.all.min.js

we tried with new changes of kendo, without **Unsafe** prefix but it's throwing dynamic script errors, kendo-controles not working. Our assumption is there are dynamic inline script Generations for Kendo controls which not contains nonce which may cause an issue.
We also tried with **Deferred-Script** but no use.
we are facing console issues related to Style and Scripts. Help me out.
Thanks.